# Tilda ups when use code cpp snippets

Tags: listings, verbatim, minted, code

I use C++ code snippets with latex. I try to use verbatim, lstlisting and minted(imho which is the most beautiful). But they has one trouble. When I want to write code p->~T() I get tilda at the top of my line:

[image: tilda ups].

How can I fix this or what code package wouldn't ups my tilda?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
void destroy(T* p) {
  p->~T();
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `minted` says something about the “high tilde” and recommends to use `lmodern` for lowering it.

[image]

However, `lmodern` does not support the T2A encoding. If your `minted` listings don't need Cyrillic you can use a not very well-known feature of `fancyvrb` (on which `minted` is built). The feature is the possibility to say

```
fontfamily=myFont
```

in the setup for `fancyvrb` (or `minted`, in this case) and to redefine `\myFont` to the desired combination of encoding and font family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{minted}

\renewcommand{\myFont}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}

\setminted{
  fontfamily=myFont,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
void destroy(T* p) {
  p->~T();
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did not show a test document but I would guess you are using Computer modern, most fonts do not follow that high `~`, latin modern is very similar font but produces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

\verb|p->~T()|

\end{document}
```

Or with the larger example, note you need to switch back to T1 to use the latin modern tt font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\usepackage[warn]{mathtext}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\begin{minted}{cpp}
void destroy(T* p) {
  p->~T();
}
\end{minted}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Question edited. Your solution does not work with minted. Or should I use only \verb?

Comment: @dasfex it [works with minted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbqW6.png) but not with the T2A encoding that you have as default as latin modern doesn't support cyrillic so it switches fonts, you would need to find a font that supports cyrillic with a normal `~` or simply switch to `\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont`  before the code block so it uses latin modern tt

Comment: @dasfex added a complete document example

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you!